# tsconfig "paths" are compiled and included by tsc? How can you stop this?

Tags: typescript

Imagine the following project structure

```
/src
  index.ts
  a.ts
/external
  external.ts
```

When using the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@external/*": "../external/*"
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

The output will contain the external package

```
/dist
  /src
    a.d.ts
    a.js
    index.d.ts
    index.js
  /external
    external.d.ts
    external.js
```

When what I wanted was

```
/dist
  a.d.ts
  a.js
  index.d.ts
  index.js
```

Even when I add `"external"` in the `exclude` option, it still compiles and includes the external package.

Is there a way to avoid compiling the external module and consume it as it is?

EDIT: For context, the external module is compiled separately. The path is simply for getting types at dev time.

Answer (score 1):

TS compiles [all files in the project directory](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#details)  per default. You can `exclude` input files, but if you `import` something from `../external/*` via module resolution, there is no way to exclude the module.

What is happening is: TS sees, that one compilation source is outside `./src` (`external.ts`) and sets its [`rootDir`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/tsconfig#rootDir) config option automatically to be the parent folder of `./src` and `./external`. That is the reason, why you get the additional nesting in `./dist`.

So what to do? You can rename the `external.ts` file to a `.d.ts` extension, so a) you still have the types, b) the compiler will see the file only as input and doesn't create nested output in `./dist` anymore. (But I am not sure, how your separate build works.)

In addition, it could probably be a good idea to set the external module as separate npm package, which you then will have placed in `node_modules` via [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html) or other mechanisms. The compiler doesn't compile them per default, so it also solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use webpack configs like so

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  externals: {
    '@external': 'external'
  }
};
```

and build your applications with `--extraWebpackConfig webpack.extra.js`.